# Spring boot does not find new classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot application, and with a controller class, a model class etc. Whenever I want to add any new class, let's say model class. I can find it in the IDE and import it in other classes. But when I build the app, I get compiling errors saying that the class could not be found.

I have tried to clean the project, invalidate caches and restart and more. When I look into the bin folder, then my new model class is missing there. So for some reason, it doesn't get added there. It is a Spring Boot application with Gradle. I would appreciate any help as I am totally new to Spring Boot and I have to maintain this project.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:447) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:268) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:147) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at io.myproject.service.ServiceApplicationKt.main(ServiceApplication.kt:42) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/myproject/service/domain/model/Store
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:448) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:635) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:670) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.myproject.service.domain.model.Store
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a solution to the problem. My project is in Kotlin, and my new model class is in Java. I thought it was okay to mix them, but it turns out I have to specify in build.gradle.kt where my java classes are going to be.

Add this to your build.gradle.kt

```
configure<SourceSetContainer> {
    named("main") {
        java.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `src/main/kotlin` as the name suggests is for Kotlin, you should place java in `src/main/java` and not in `src/main/kotlin`. Which is the reason for not finding them in the first place as the java setup will look in `src/main/java` .

Comment: Aha you see, thanks for clarifying further. However it would be messy if I put my java classes in it's own directory. Suppose I have a mixed project, and I want one folder for all models instead of two models folders. Then the above line makes it possible

Comment: Messy is in the eye of the beholder I guess. I like the separation between the 2, the same for other languages, they have default paths.